# Sql server pass in date value as parameter with convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, variables

I have written a sql that select data between a date and a another.
Basically the problem is about the date format that i wanted to made some selection

My coloum name is date_tm and sample data like this: 2011-04-04 00:30:19.107

My Sql like this:

```
DECLARE @Date_From DATETIME;
DECLARE @Date_To DATETIME；

SET @Date_From = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()),0)-1,120);
SET @Date_To = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()),0)-1,120);

select distinct no, lot
from database.dbo.TblName
Where Convert(varchar(10), Date_Tm, 120) Between '@Date_From' And '@Date_To';
```

I try to debug it using this

```
Print(@Date_From);
Print(@Date_To);
```

The output is something like this "Nov  6 2011 12:00AM" am i not convert its alreadly?
and then i tested with select statement like this:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()),0)-1,120);
```

The output is something like this "2011-11-06" why its work here?

Select result is nothing =="

Then i do a lot of testing regarding this date format
I try to direct parse in date_from and Date_to

```
where Convert(varchar(10), Date_Tm, 120) Between '2011-04-04' And '2011-04-04'
```

I get what is expected

Anyway,what i wanted is get data by a range of date.I am crushing my head with this convert method =="

Please help me.

Thanks:

PS:Please dont hesitate to voice out my mistake. we all learn from mistake and sorry for my poor english.

Regards:

LiangCk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are declaring your two variables as datetime instead of varchar(10).  SQL is automatically converting it back to datetime because your variables are datetime.

```
DECLARE @Date_From VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @Date_To VARCHAR(10)；
```

Comment: &%*@(%@)%@@ what a stupid question i ask ...thanks Norlando
I fix it with just change the datetime to varchar(10)
like this:DECLARE @Date_From VARCHAR(10);

Comment: @LiangCk, no problem just a simple mistake I make them all the time.